# Estimate compressibility of file

Tags: compression, gzip

Is there a quick and dirty way of estimating `gzip`-compressibility of a file without having to fully compress it with `gzip`?

I could, in `bash`, do

```
bc <<<"scale=2;$(gzip -c file | wc -c)/$(wc -c <file)"
```

This gives me the compression factor without having to write the `gz` file to disk; this way I can avoid replacing a file on disk with its `gz` version if the resultant disk space savings do not justify the trouble. But with this approach the file is indeed fully put through `gzip`; it's just that the output is piped to `wc` rather than written to disk.

Is there a way to get a rough compressibility estimate for a file without having `gzip` work on all its contents?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try compressing one every 10 blocks for instance to get an idea:

```
perl -MIPC::Open2 -nE 'BEGIN{$/=\4096;open2(\*I,\*O,"gzip|wc -c")}
                       if ($. % 10 == 1) {print O $_; $l+=length}
                       END{close O; $c = <I>; say $c/$l}'
```

(here with 4K blocks).

Answer (score 5):

Here's a (hopefully equivalent) Python version of [Stephane Chazelas's](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22565/st%C3%A9phane-chazelas) [solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/155919/21233)

```
python -c "
import zlib
from itertools import islice
from functools import partial
import sys
with open(sys.argv[1], "rb") as f:
  compressor = zlib.compressobj()
  t, z = 0, 0.0
  for chunk in islice(iter(partial(f.read, 4096), b''), 0, None, 10):
    t += len(chunk)
    z += len(compressor.compress(chunk))
  z += len(compressor.flush())
  print(z/t)
" file
```

Comment: I don't know if that's equivalent (as python is not by cup of coffee ;-b)), but that gives slightly different results (even for very large files where the gzip header size overhead can be ignored), possibly because zlib.compressobj uses different settings than gzip (I find that it's closer to `gzip -3`) or maybe because zlib.compressobj compresses each chunk in isolation (as opposed to a stream as a whole). In any case both approaches should be good enough.  I find that perl is slightly faster.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, judging by the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/zlib.html#zlib.compressobj) `compressobj` should be acting on the stream as a whole. I find that both Python and Perl solutions produce approximately the same result on my data files (they differ in the second decimal place, that's good enough for me). Thanks for the great idea

Comment: Thanks, this is super handy. Is there any way to use this in Python without thrashing the standby memory or to reduce the data this reads? Because it appears more data is being read into memory than compressed (since it does it every 10 blocks, but the whole file is read anyway).

Comment: @Testerhood, a naive way might involve seeking forward 10 blocks, read 1 block, rinse and repeat. Having said that I am not sure if doing that would prevent file-caching effects (in other words prevent the i0 block ignore-worthy chunks from being read into memory). This is worthy of a new question

Comment: @iruvar Alright, thanks for the suggestion :) I will share my results if I can manage to make improvements.

Answer (score 2):

I had a multi-gigabyte file and I wasn't sure if it was compressed, so I test-compressed the first 10M bytes:

```
head -c 10000000 large_file.bin | gzip | wc -c
```

It's not perfect but it worked well for me.

Comment: aidan, a compressibility estimation based on a contiguous subset of the file could yield misleading results if the compressibility varies from one part of the file to the other - Stephane's sampling approach is superior in this regard

Comment: @iruvar Agreed. As I say, it's not perfect, but it'll definitely tell you the difference between a gigabyte of ascii text and a gigabyte of H.264. It also has the highest chance of running in very stripped down environments (Perl may be missing).

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a quick script to recursively check each file in a directory and then only compress the most compressible files. It grabs a couple of megabytes in the interior of the file and tests them with `gzip --fast`, then it uses `xz` to compress the file if needed.

You can run it with: ./compress.if.compressible dir_name

```
cores=$(grep '^core id' /proc/cpuinfo | sort -u | wc -l)

IFS=$'\n'
for file in $(find "$1" -type f); do

#Skip small files. The savings is minimal and sometimes xz just makes these larger.
size_b=`du --apparent-size -b "$file" | sed 's/\t.*//'`
if [[ $size_b -le 1024 ]]; then
    echo -e "\nSkipping small file $file"
    continue
fi

size=`du --apparent-size --block-size=1M "$file" | sed 's/\t.*//'`
reduction=$(dd if="$file" bs=1M count=2 skip=$(expr $size / 3) 2>/dev/null | gzip --fast -v 2>&1 > /dev/null)

echo -e "\n$reduction $file"

if [[ $(echo $reduction | sed 's/\..*//') -ge 20 ]]; then
    echo "$size_b * .9 > 90" | bc
    xz -v -T $cores "$file"
    new_size=`du --apparent-size -b "$file.xz" | sed 's/\t.*//'`
    if [[ `echo "$new_size * 100 / $size_b" | bc` -ge 90 ]]; then
        echo "Insufficent Compression. Reverting..."
        unxz "$file.xz"
    fi
fi

done
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an improved Python version based on iruvar's [awesome solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/155927/418284). The main improvement is that the script reads only the data blocks from disk that it actually compresses:

```python
import zlib
def Predict_file_compression_ratio(MyFilePath):
 blocksize = (4096 * 1) # Increase if you want to read more bytes per block at once.
 blocksize_seek = 0

 # r = read, b = binary
 with open(MyFilePath, "rb") as f:
  # Make a zlib compressor object, and set compression level.
  # 1 is fastest, 9 is slowest
  compressor = zlib.compressobj(1)
  t, z, counter = 0, 0, 0

  while True:
    # Use this modulo calculation to check every "number" of blocks.
    if counter % 10 == 0:
      # Seek to the correct byte position of the file.
      f.seek(blocksize_seek)
      # The block above will be read, increase the seek distance by one block for the next iteration.
      blocksize_seek += blocksize
      # Read data chunk of file into this variable.
      data = f.read(blocksize)
      
      # Stop if there are no more data.
      if not data:
        # For zlib: Flush any remaining compressed data. Not doing this can lead to a tiny inaccuracy.
        z += len(compressor.flush())
        break

      # Uncompressed data size, add size to variable to get a total value.
      t += len(data)
      # Compressed data size
      z += len(compressor.compress(data))

    # When we skip, we want to increase the seek distance. This is vital for correct skipping.
    else:
      blocksize_seek += blocksize
    # Increase the block / iteration counter.
    counter += 1

 # Print the results. But avoid division by 0 >_>
 if not t == 0:
  print('Compression ratio: ' + str(z/t))
 else:
  print('Compression ratio: none, file has no content.')
 print('Compressed: ' + str(z))
 print('Uncompressed: ' + str(t))
```

If high data rates are crucial and accurate compression ratios not so much, you can use lz4 instead. It's great if you only want to find out what files can be compressed the most, with low CPU usage. This module needs to be installed with pip [from here](https://pypi.org/project/lz4/). In the Python code itself, you pretty much only need this:

```python
import lz4.block
z += len(lz4.block.compress(data))
```

Please note, I observed that using this script does thrash the standby memory (does for sure on Windows), which degrades file performance - especially on computers with classic hard drives, and if you use this function for lots of files at once. This memory trashing can be avoided by setting a low memory page priority on the script's Python process. I opted to do this with AutoHotkey on Windows. Helpful source [here](https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=34551).

Comment: Is it also possible to predict compression time with this information?